# Authentic LEGO legs and the Lego imprint

Tags: minifigures

I've gotten a pair of minifigure legs new out of the box with no 'LEGO' logo on the underside of the top of the foot a while ago. I've purchased new pieces where only one leg is imprinted. And as of late, all legs have been imprinted. Same thing with headgear and helmets. Some have the LEGO logo, some don't. When did Lego start imprinting 'Lego' inside the toes on plain leg assemblies?

Comment: Hi matisyoyo and welcome to Bricks.SE! I've taken the liberty to edit your question a bit in order to make it easier to read, but to make it truly answerable, we'd like to ask you to provide additional details on what kind of help do you expect. As of now, you are only stating your current situation without asking or even implying a question. We could infer one of the possible ones and answer that, but chances are you had another (if similar) question in mind. So please edit your post and add a question there. Thanks!

Comment: Just to add to what Zovits said, if you are questioning if your elements are original LEGO - please add some pictures.

Comment: See also: [When did LEGO Minifigure leg mold designs change](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/9948/56)