# Are my LEGO Star Wars Royal Guards with black hands counterfeit?

Tags: minifigures, star-wars

At the current moment due to my camera being busted on my phone and the protective glass on it being shattered my camera can't take anything more than a legit blur.

However I've come here to say the legs have no LEGO stamp on the inside. Nor does the helmet. Its the newer Black gloved Royal Guards. The LEGO stamp is on the neck piece and in-between the leg prongs on top. But no where else.

Also the arms don't have a LEGO stamp, they just say 04-B02 L with a underline. The red plastic even seems a odd tinge of color. I bought them off Bricklink.

If anyone has one of these Royal Guards can they clue me in?

Comment: Can you include a set number, or a link to the exact figure on BrickLink?

Comment: lego Star Wars 852552 the magnet ones. Apparently the seller on bricklink (Name will be left out) had said they were from the magnet set. The helmets squeak, and they feel odd compared to other guards. If anyone has those type figures I'd like to know if their the same as mine. So that I may sleep at night knowing my stuff isn't counterfeit.

Comment: https://brickset.com/sets/852552-1/Magnet-Set-Royal-Guard-2009

Comment: @chicks yeah that one. Thanks for linking it. Does anyone have those specific guards?

Comment: Some odd sets like magnets have a tendency to be produced in China. It could be a case, where different mould (and slightly different plastic formula for colour too) has been used there, which has different markings on produced elements. Does PIP (Plastic Injection Point) is the same on both of your questionable and known-to-be-LEGO elements?

Comment: Not being rude alex but your grammar is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

That set was produced from around 2009, and [anecdotally, we've seen that](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/9948/56) the LEGO logo wasn't really added to the leg elements until around 2013.

There are also [examples of legitimate accessories](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/14650/56) having no logo on them as well.

Comment: Funny because I have royal guards from the original Emperor arrives set and they have lego stamps on their helmets. That set is about 5 years older than the magnet set. This is not a answer. I want someone that specifically has a magnet set guard that can show the legs and helmet if they can. This is a good eye you have here on this but not quite correct. Lego head gear especially star wars got stamps. The imperial inspection set that is. And the helmets on the guards have stamps on their feet and helmet. Not their arms though.